# Matrix of differences in Python, result like MATLAB's bsxfun

Tags: python, matrix

I have a Nx1 vector of values. What I would like to do is create a NxN matrix where each value represents the difference between the ith and jth value - sort of like a large correlation matrix. I've done with this with a loop but I'm looking for a more elegant way to approach using Python's vectorization capabilities as this vector may get quite large. I realize there are a few questions out there with abstract answers.

How can I replicate MATLAB's `bsxfun` function in Python?

I posted a question on SE to discover the `bsxfun` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422606/matlab-matrix-of-differences), but now need to do the same in Python.

Comment: Did you even try [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946810/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-matlab-function-bsxfun-in-python)?

Comment: Yes, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946810/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-matlab-function-bsxfun-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454685/translating-a-line-of-matlab-bsxfun-rdivide-to-python, and the broadcasting tutorial here http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc, did you really need to downvote? You didn't even post a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you want, but `numpy`'s broadcasting rules (see [here](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) for an introduction) mean that most of the time `bsxfun` isn't needed because it Just Works(tm).  For example, if I understand what you're getting at, something like

```
>>> a = np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
>>> a - a[:,None]
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8],
       [-2,  0,  2,  4,  6],
       [-4, -2,  0,  2,  4],
       [-6, -4, -2,  0,  2],
       [-8, -6, -4, -2,  0]])
```

should work.

Comment: Ah perfect. I was mistakenly using a-a.T which of course was returning an array of 0s. Thanks.